# How to find frame to given WebElement?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

I am writing a Selenium testcase for a webpage which has multiple frames and WebElements. My goal is to get a specific WebElement by xpath without knowing anything about the iframes before starting the testcase.

What would be the best way to identify the iframe in which the WebElement I am searching for is located?

I created a pseudocode function which might work, but I am not sure if it's the best way:

1. Create a list with all iFrames found via the html-frame tag
2. Iterate through every list
3. set the driver focus to the list element
4. search for the WebElement I want to have
5. If WebElement is not null return it

Is there any better way to solve this problem?

Comment: If there is no unique identifier , thats a good approach you have there. The right thing will be to ask dev team to add unique ID to the frame in which it  appears . Else the test would be so brittle

Comment: Each iframe holds a separate dom tree. How would you know which element is the proper one if you would have the element in several frames?

Comment: I would try to make sure that the xpath of the element I am searching for is unique